# How to add custom interceptor in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-http-interceptors

I have written a custom interceptor on angular 4. The issue I am having is checking URL with dynamic path variable in the URL. The backend application has Oauth2 and it's deployed in a separate server(Authorization and Resource). The interceptor class of the angular is below

```
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private whiteList = [
        'http://localhost:8081/Test1app/oauth-server/oauth/token',
        'http://localhost:8080/ResourceApp/oauth-resource/ibex/api/signup',
        'http://localhost:8080/ResourceApp/oauth-resource/ibex/api/registeration/confirm/**',
        'http://localhost:8080/ResourceApp/oauth-resource/ibex/api/user/profile/upload',
        'http://localhost:8080/ResourceApp/oauth-resource/ibex/api/profile/edit/password/**'
    ]
    constructor(public auth : AuthenticationService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log(request.url);
        // If request is not in whitlist add header
        if (!this.whiteList.includes(request.url)) {
            console.log("I was not here");
            console.log(request.url);
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }

}
```

the issue that I am facing now is whenever I try to access http://localhost:8080/ResourceApp/oauth-resource/ibex/api/profile/edit/password/12345-2333-4444
it's going under the if condition (request is in the whitelist)

Comment: Have you tried `request.urlWithParams`? Also, note that the `/**` in whiteList array elements is probably not working as you expect.  Array.prototype.includes() uses the sameValueZero algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private patterns = [
    new RegExp('http://localhost:8081/Test1app/oauth-server/oauth/token'),
    new RegExp('http://localhost:8080/ResourceApp/oauth-resource/ibex/api/signup'),
    new RegExp('http://localhost:8080/ResourceApp/oauth-resource/ibex/api/registeration/confirm/.*'),
    new RegExp('http://localhost:8080/ResourceApp/oauth-resource/ibex/api/user/profile/upload'),
    new RegExp('http://localhost:8080/ResourceApp/oauth-resource/ibex/api/profile/edit/password/.*')
  ];

  constructor(public auth : AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!this.match(request.url)) {
      request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}` } });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }

  match(url: string): boolean {
    for (const pattern of this.patterns) {
      if (Array.isArray(url.match(pattern))) { return true; }
    }

    return false;
  }

}
```

References:

[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Going through for loop will affect the application performance since every request come through the interceptor and the white list might get bigger in the future. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @joel `includes` also loops the array. There is no dark magic behind it. The only way to avoid that is not using an array at all. Try using only a regex that matches all urls that require the header or one regex that matches all urls that don't require the header.

Comment: What is the import for new RegExp()? In typescript?